# Not able to fetch element by CSS selector on Chrome (using developer tools and Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: html, google-chrome, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

Below is the source of a login page. When I try to find an element using a CSS selector (using Selenium WebDriver or a watch expression in Chrome developer tools) I can't find it. Using Chrome developer tools, every watch expression gives me the message **"Not available"**. I have trying to identify what the problem is with this HTML, but I am so far unable to do that.

More surprisingly, the same CSS selector works well on Firefox.

Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">       
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>           
    </head>
    <body >
      <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="w900">
         <!--header start-->
         <div id="loginheader">
          <div class="logo1" style="padding-top:30px;">
           <img src="/openam/images/logo.png" width="122" height="49" alt="Logo"  align="absmiddle"/>                  
          </div>
          <div class="login-home">
           <div class="home-login-cnt">

            <!-- Start OpenAM Code -->
            <form   name="Login"  action="/openam/UI/Login"  method="post">

             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      <!--
              elmCount++;
              -->
             </script>

             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
              <!--
              elmCount++;
              -->
             </script>

             <span class="fL">
              <!--input name="" type="text" value="Email address"  class="round"/>-->
              <input class="round" type="text" placeholder="Email address" name="IDToken1" id="IDToken1" value="" />
             </span>

             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
              <!--
              elmCount++;
              -->
             </script>

             <span class="fL">
              <!--<input name="IDToken2" type="text" value="Password"  class="round"/>-->
              <input class="round" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="IDToken2" id="IDToken2" value="" />
             </span>

             <fieldset>
              <div class="row">
               <input name="Login.Submit" type="submit" onclick="LoginSubmit('Log In'); return false;" class="login-button fR" value="Sign In" />
              </div>
             </fieldset>

             <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
              <!--
              if (elmCount != null) {
               document.write("<input name=\"IDButton"  + "\" type=\"hidden\">");
              }
              -->
             </script>

             <input type="hidden" name="goto" value="aHR0cDovL2dsbzM0LnN0YWdpbmctcG9ydGFsLmNzcmxicy5jb206ODAvcmV0YWlsLw==" />
             <input type="hidden" name="gotoOnFail" value=""/>
             <input type="hidden" name="SunQueryParamsString" value="cmVhbG09Z2xvMzQm" />
             <input type="hidden" name="encoded" value="true" />                        
             <input type="hidden" name="gx_charset" value="UTF-8"/>
            </form>
            <!-- End OpenAM Code-->
           </div>
           <div class="forget-password "><b>Forgot password?</b></div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <!--header End-->
         <div class="cb"></div>
         <div class="cb10"></div>
         <div class="w100p">
          <img src="/openam/images/login-bg.jpg" width="998" height="548" align="absmiddle" />
         </div>
         <div class="cb10"></div>
         <div class="cb10"></div>
         <div class="cb10"></div>
         <div class="w100p">
          <div style="width:475px; float:left">
           <div style=" background:url(/openam/images/border0img.png) right repeat-y">
            <div class="cb10"></div>
            <span><img src="/openam/images/learnmore.png" width="202" height="59" style="margin-left:140px;"/></span>
            <div class="cb"></div>
            <span class="fR" style="margin-right:130px; color:#767571; font-size:14px; font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode"><b>learn more ></b></span>
            <div class="cb10"></div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div style="width:370px; float:left">
           <div style="">
            <div class="cb10"></div>
             <div class="w100p">
              <span style="float:left; margin-left:140px; font-size:16px; font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode; ">
               <span class="fL w100p" style="color:#996666">for assistance contact:</span>
               <div class="cb10"></div>
               <span class="fL w100p" style="color:#000">support@abc.com</span>
               <div class="cb10"></div>
               <span class="fL" style="color:#000">support@xyz.com</span>
              </span>
             </div>
             <div class="cb10"></div>
             <div class="cb10"></div>
            </div>
           </div>                 
           <div class="cb10"></div>
           <div class="cb10"></div>
           <div class="cb10"></div>
           <div class="cb10"></div>
           <div class="cb10"></div>
           <div class="footer">
            <ul>
             <li>Copyright © 2012-13 plc. All rights reserved. Terms of Use  |  Privacy Policy</li>
            </ul>
            <span>Help | Feedback</span> 
           </div>
          </div>                
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well *what* CSS selector are you using?!

Comment: I repeat @Arran's comment: what CSS selector are you using?